# Is there way to get array length using firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have array inside document in firestore , This array has approximate 284 item , Is there way to get array length ?

I don't have any code about that but you can leave simple example or method name , Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @AlexMamo I can solve it by put data in array and get array length but is there method is ready by firebase to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple function to get the length of an array in a document.  What you will have to do is [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get()) the document, then [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get(java.lang.String)) the array field from the DocumentSnapshot, and get the size of the List object from that field.